# Search bar in React TS not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I used this example snippet written in ReactJS to try and create a search box in my website, which is written in React TS

https://codemyui.com/input-highlight-seen-tripadvisor/

However when I have tried to convert it, I get the following issues

1) Input is read only, ie I cannot type into it

2) I am not sure what to do with this bit of the style in the original CSS, as it does not compile when I paste it into my CSS

```
&:focus {
    + .input-highlight {
      border-top: 3px solid #fbc91b;
    }
  }
```

Can someone point out what I have done wrong in the conversion to TS?

My React control

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';

interface ISearchBarState {
    inputValue : string
  }

class SearchBar extends React.Component<{}, ISearchBarState> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          inputValue: ''
        };

        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
      }

      public render() {
        const { inputValue } = this.state;

       return (<div className='input-wrapper'>
           <input
             placeholder='Search...'
             value={inputValue}
             spellCheck={false}
             />
           <span className='input-highlight'>
           { inputValue.replace(/ /g, "\u00a0") }
         </span>  
         </div>);          
    }

    private onInputChange(e: any) {
        const { value } = e.target;

        this.setState({
          inputValue: value
        });
      }


}

export default SearchBar;
```

and my CSS

```
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.input-highlight {
  font-size: 16;
  user-select: none;
  line-height: 20;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #999999;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  color: transparent;
  font-family: Roboto Slab, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 3px solid #fbc91b;
}

input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  line-height: 2;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 16;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
  font-family: Roboto Slab, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the bit of css in question

```
&:focus {
+ .input-highlight {
    border-top: 3px solid #fbc91b;
  }
}
```

is actually [scss](https://sass-lang.com/), you'd need to compile that bit to css first or manually compile it to css. Here, below I help to manually change it to css for you

```
input:focus .input-highlight{
   border-top: 3px solid #fbc91b;
}
```

you can add this css snippet to your css file, put it below the input css block.

Comment: Ok great thanks for that. I still have the first problem however, with the control not accepting input and seeming readonly

Comment: May I know how did you add the tsx file to your page? Is it a react page? Have you transpiled the tsx code to js bundle? Have you checked out [create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) on how to startup a react web app?

Comment: Yes I used create-react-app with a TS option script to create a TS project. I read something in the docs that if you set a value of a control then it becomes read only - but I didn't quite understand that - as surely you want to be able to bind the value to the state and allow a user to enter something?

Comment: Ah yes, I removed the line in the input control saying value={inputValue} and now it works. Surprising as that was in the original snippet online and that seemed to work. Maybe its a TS thing?

Comment: Yep, the `onChange` handler in the input should already handle the state update for the input value. The `value={inputValue}` theoretically should have no effect whether it's added or removed. If removing that property fixes the issue, then feel free to remove it from your code!